# In the Software Foundations Trie module, what is a good implementation of is_trie?

Tags: coq

The module is here: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/vfa-current/Trie.html

If you search "Definition is_trie", you can find the following definition and the portion that I'm unsure about

```
Definition is_trie {A: Type} (t: trie_table A) : Prop
(* REPLACE THIS LINE WITH ":= _your_definition_ ." *). Admitted.
```

So... I just used the following definition:

```
Definition is_trie {A: Type} (t: trie_table A) : Prop = True
```

And...I was able to do all of the proofs, including the final one that has the following comment:

```
(* Change this to Qed once you have is_trie defined and working. *)
```

So, there are a couple of possibilities. One is that this is a sort of test from the creators of software foundations. Another is that they didn't get into the sorts of proofs that would need a stronger invariant. I'm not sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah the invariant is trivial. All tries are valid. Actually almost any stronger invariant would make it impossible to prove either `empty_is_trie` or `insert_is_trie`.

Comment: Haha, so cruel, but good to know I wasn't crazy. Software Foundations is not afraid to do stuff like this...which is great, but can also make me question myself! Thank you!